# Tips for debugging fixture foreign key errors in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixtures

I'm getting a Foreign Key error in my fixture setup, and I'm stumped as to how to go about debugging it.

Specifically, I'm getting the error below, but I know the label exists:

```
RuntimeError: Foreign key violations found in your fixture data. Ensure you aren't referring to labels that don't exist on associations.
```

Here is the setup:  I have Users, Categories, and Entries.  Each category has a user, and each entry has 12 categories.

The offending Entry fixture is

```
bob_2022_01_10:
  date: 2022-01-10
  segment: 3
  user: bob
  category_0: test
  # categories can be null, so I don't set category_1 through category_11 for this example.
```

And, if I comment out the `category_0` line, everything works.

The Category fixture is

```
test:
  id: 100
  name: Test category
  user: bob
  parent_id: nil
```

If I comment out the offending line in the Entry fixture, I can use the `test` fixture in other tests. (Hence, I know the problem isn't that I'm referencing a fixture that doesn't exist.)

I can set up the relationship between an entry and a category "by hand" in my test:

```
   entry = entries :bob_2022_01_10
   entry.category_0 = categories :test
```

I can also set up the fixture using a category_id instead of a fixture name:

```
bob_2022_01_10:
  date: 2022-01-10
  segment: 3
  user: bob
  category_0_id: 100
```

I wonder if the problem is the way I set up the foreign keys in `Entry.rb`:

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord

  LAST_SEGMENT = 11

  belongs_to :user

  validate :validate_category_owner
  
  (0..LAST_SEGMENT).each do |time_segment|
    belongs_to "category_#{time_segment}".to_sym, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "category_#{time_segment}_id", optional: true
   end
```

However, that would be odd because everything but the fixture setup works.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

---

If it helps, I'll include the schema also:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2022_01_15_023305) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "order"
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.integer "parent_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["parent_id"], name: "index_categories_on_parent_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_categories_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "entries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "date"
    t.integer "segment"
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.integer "category_0_id"
    t.integer "category_1_id"
    t.integer "category_2_id"
    t.integer "category_3_id"
    t.integer "category_4_id"
    t.integer "category_5_id"
    t.integer "category_6_id"
    t.integer "category_7_id"
    t.integer "category_8_id"
    t.integer "category_9_id"
    t.integer "category_10_id"
    t.integer "category_11_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["category_0_id"], name: "index_entries_on_category_0_id"
    t.index ["category_10_id"], name: "index_entries_on_category_10_id"
    t.index ["category_11_id"], name: "index_entries_on_category_11_id"
    t.index ["category_1_id"], name: "index_entries_on_category_1_id"
    t.index ["category_2_id"], name: "index_entries_on_category_2_id"
    t.index ["category_3_id"], name: "index_entries_on_category_3_id"
    t.index ["category_4_id"], name: "index_entries_on_category_4_id"
    t.index ["category_5_id"], name: "index_entries_on_category_5_id"
    t.index ["category_6_id"], name: "index_entries_on_category_6_id"
    t.index ["category_7_id"], name: "index_entries_on_category_7_id"
    t.index ["category_8_id"], name: "index_entries_on_category_8_id"
    t.index ["category_9_id"], name: "index_entries_on_category_9_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_entries_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "fname"
    t.string "lname"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.boolean "admin"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "categories", "categories", column: "parent_id"
  add_foreign_key "categories", "users"
  add_foreign_key "entries", "categories", column: "category_0_id"
  add_foreign_key "entries", "categories", column: "category_10_id"
  add_foreign_key "entries", "categories", column: "category_11_id"
  add_foreign_key "entries", "categories", column: "category_1_id"
  add_foreign_key "entries", "categories", column: "category_2_id"
  add_foreign_key "entries", "categories", column: "category_3_id"
  add_foreign_key "entries", "categories", column: "category_4_id"
  add_foreign_key "entries", "categories", column: "category_5_id"
  add_foreign_key "entries", "categories", column: "category_6_id"
  add_foreign_key "entries", "categories", column: "category_7_id"
  add_foreign_key "entries", "categories", column: "category_8_id"
  add_foreign_key "entries", "categories", column: "category_9_id"
  add_foreign_key "entries", "users"
end
```

Comment: I added it above.

Comment: Is there a way to access the list of Category fixtures by name from the Entry fixtures .yml file?  If so, I could embed some Ruby there and potentially debug what the issue is (missing name, invalid key, etc.)

Comment: It would be helpful if the error message included the name of the offending table(s).

Answer (score 14):

The problem here is the error `RuntimeError: Foreign key violations found in your fixture data. Ensure you aren't referring to labels that don't exist on associations` didn't any help, [this actually replaced the real error](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb#L632-L634).

```rb
  if ActiveRecord.verify_foreign_keys_for_fixtures && !conn.all_foreign_keys_valid?
     raise "Foreign key violations found in your fixture data..."
  end
```

According to the code above, you either disable `verify_foreign_keys_for_fixtures`

```rb
# config/application.rb
config.active_record.verify_foreign_keys_for_fixtures = false
```

or figure out what the error (db level) behind. In order to do that, you need to run  manually the sql in the method [all_foreign_keys_valid?](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/referential_integrity.rb#L41-L71) above

```rb
def all_foreign_keys_valid?
  sql = <<~SQL
  #....
  SQL

    begin
      transaction(requires_new: true) do
         execute(sql)
      end

      true
    # rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
    #    false
    rescue => e
      puts e # this will show the db level error
    end
end
```

In my case, the db error was `permission denied ...`, i need to grant the db user to SUPERUSER, your case might not be the same. In the bottom line, the tip: run the sql manually to figure out the root cause.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem today. If you set up an `id` in your fixture element then you can only reference it by the id and not the name of the fixture element.

So if you comment out `id: 100` in your Category fixture, then you should be able to use `category_0: test` in your Entry fixture.